# Are there any other methods left to create a spiral of equidistant segments?

Tags: diagrams, pstricks, pst-node, pst-plot, multido

I want to create a spiral that is composed of equidistant segments as shown in the following figure. I tried to draw it with various methods. The colors are used to distinguish each method from the others.

[image]

The methods I used are:

### `\translate(!CP \tx@UserCoor)` with `\multido` and `\lineto`

It is my original idea.

```
\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[linecolor=red]
{
    \moveto(0,0)
    \multido{\r=0.1+0.1}{89}{\translate(!CP \tx@UserCoor)\lineto(!1 \r\space sqrt 700 mul PtoC)}
}
\end{pspicture}
\makeatother
```

### `\translate(!CP \tx@UserCoor)` with `\multido` and `\psline`

It is my original idea.

```
\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[linecolor=green]
{
    \moveto(0,0)
    \multido{\r=0.1+0.1}{89}{\translate(!CP \tx@UserCoor)\psline(!1 \r\space sqrt 700 mul PtoC)}
}
\end{pspicture}
\makeatother
```

### `\rlineto` with `\multido`

It is my original idea.

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[linecolor=blue]
{
    \moveto(0,0)
    \multido{\r=0.1+0.1}{89}{\rlineto(!1 \r\space sqrt 700 mul PtoC)}
}
\end{pspicture}
```

### `\psVector` with `\multido`

It is Herbert's idea.

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psset{showpoints,dotstyle=o,dotscale=2,linecolor=red}
    \psStartPoint(0,0)
    \multido{\r=0.1+0.1}{89}{\psVector[arrows=-](!1 \r\space sqrt 700 mul PtoC)}
\end{pspicture}
```

### `\psnline` with `\multido`, concatenated `\points` and `\expandafter`

It is Jake's idea.

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\def\points{(0,0)}%
\multido{\r=0.1+0.1}{89}{\xdef\points{\points(!1 \r\space sqrt 700 mul PtoC)}}
\psset{linecolor=green}
\expandafter\psrline\points
\end{pspicture}
```

### `\curvepnodes` with temporary variables

It is Christoph's idea.

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \pstVerb{tx@NodeDict begin /myX -1 def /myY 0 def end }%
  \curvepnodes[plotpoints=90]{0}{89}{%
    myX myY
    t 0.1 mul sqrt 700 mul 1 exch PtoC
    3 -1 roll add 3 1 roll add exch
    2 copy /myY ED /myX ED
  }{P}
  \psnline[linecolor=blue](0,\Pnodecount){P} 
\end{pspicture}
```

### `\psparametricplot` with temporary variables

It is Christoph's idea applied to `\psparametricplot`.

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \pstVerb{/myX -1 def /myY 0 def}%
  \psparametricplot[plotpoints=90,linecolor=red]{0}{89}{%
    myX myY
    t 0.1 mul sqrt 700 mul 1 exch PtoC
    3 -1 roll add 3 1 roll add exch
    2 copy /myY ED /myX ED
  }
\end{pspicture}
```

### `\curvepnodes` with `for` loop

It is Christoph's idea.

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \curvepnodes[plotpoints=90]{0}{89}{%
    -1 0 
        0 1 t
        {
            0.1 mul sqrt 700 mul 1 exch PtoC
            3 -1 roll add 3 1 roll add exch
    } for 
  }{P}
  \psnline[linecolor=green](0,\Pnodecount){P} 
\end{pspicture}
```

### `\psparametricplot` with `for` loop

It is Christoph's idea applied to `\psparametricplot`.

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psparametricplot[plotpoints=90,linecolor=blue]{0}{89}{%
    -1 0 
        0 1 t
        {
            0.1 mul sqrt 700 mul 1 exch PtoC
            3 -1 roll add 3 1 roll add exch
    } for 
  } 
\end{pspicture}
```

### The complete code

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset{showpoints,dotstyle=o,dotscale=2}

\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[linecolor=red]
{
    \moveto(0,0)
    \multido{\r=0.1+0.1}{89}{\translate(!CP \tx@UserCoor)\lineto(!1 \r\space sqrt 700 mul PtoC)}
}
\end{pspicture}
\makeatother



\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[linecolor=green]
{
    \moveto(0,0)
    \multido{\r=0.1+0.1}{89}{\translate(!CP \tx@UserCoor)\psline(!1 \r\space sqrt 700 mul PtoC)}
}
\end{pspicture}
\makeatother


\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom[linecolor=blue]
{
    \moveto(0,0)
    \multido{\r=0.1+0.1}{89}{\rlineto(!1 \r\space sqrt 700 mul PtoC)}
}
\end{pspicture}


\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psset{showpoints,dotstyle=o,dotscale=2,linecolor=red}
    \psStartPoint(0,0)
    \multido{\r=0.1+0.1}{89}{\psVector[arrows=-](!1 \r\space sqrt 700 mul PtoC)}
\end{pspicture}


\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\def\points{(0,0)}%
\multido{\r=0.1+0.1}{89}{\xdef\points{\points(!1 \r\space sqrt 700 mul PtoC)}}
\psset{linecolor=green}
\expandafter\psrline\points
\end{pspicture}


\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \pstVerb{tx@NodeDict begin /myX -1 def /myY 0 def end }%
  \curvepnodes[plotpoints=90]{0}{89}{%
    myX myY
    t 0.1 mul sqrt 700 mul 1 exch PtoC
    3 -1 roll add 3 1 roll add exch
    2 copy /myY ED /myX ED
  }{P}
  \psnline[linecolor=blue](0,\Pnodecount){P} 
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \pstVerb{/myX -1 def /myY 0 def}%
  \psparametricplot[plotpoints=90,linecolor=red]{0}{89}{%
    myX myY
    t 0.1 mul sqrt 700 mul 1 exch PtoC
    3 -1 roll add 3 1 roll add exch
    2 copy /myY ED /myX ED
  }
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \curvepnodes[plotpoints=90]{0}{89}{%
    -1 0 
        0 1 t
        {
            0.1 mul sqrt 700 mul 1 exch PtoC
            3 -1 roll add 3 1 roll add exch
    } for 
  }{P}
  \psnline[linecolor=green](0,\Pnodecount){P} 
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psparametricplot[plotpoints=90,linecolor=blue]{0}{89}{%
    -1 0 
        0 1 t
        {
            0.1 mul sqrt 700 mul 1 exch PtoC
            3 -1 roll add 3 1 roll add exch
    } for 
  } 
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Questions

1. How to use `\psplot` here?
2. Are there any other methods left?
3. When using `\lineto`, `\psline` and `\rlineto`, how to make `showpoints` work?

Comment: your Q looks like an answer with it's multiple scrolling needed :)

Comment: @texenthusiast: I don't think so. :-)

Comment: If there is no answer then I will delete this question shortly...

Comment: They all seem to use the same formula (a square root multiplied by 700 and then transformed to Cartesian coordinates)? What is that formula for someone inexperienced with PSTricks notation of coordinates? What is the angle between the points?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: See [Jake's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120939/19356).

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014 You should maybe ask on [meta.tex](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com) before deleting your question. I am not sure it is in an appropriate form now, but I believe this question, providing many ways to get the same result, can be interesting for other users.